# Converting MS SQL function to MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, function, converters

I'm trying to convert this MS SQL function to MYSQL, but I'm having syntax error.

Error: Syntaz error: Unexpected 'int' (int)

MS SQL Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ConvertIPV6to4]
(@AddrIPV6 varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(17)

AS

BEGIN

declare @ipv4 varchar(17)

set @ipv4 = (
select
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x' + substring(substring(@AddrIPV6, (len(@AddrIPV6)-charindex(':', @AddrIPV6)) - 3, 4), 1, 2), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x' + substring(substring(@AddrIPV6, (len(@AddrIPV6)-charindex(':', @AddrIPV6)) - 3, 4), 3, 2), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x' + substring(substring(@AddrIPV6, (len(@AddrIPV6)-charindex(':', @AddrIPV6)) + 2, 4), 1, 2), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x' + substring(substring(@AddrIPV6, (len(@AddrIPV6)-charindex(':', @AddrIPV6)) + 2, 4), 3, 2), 1)) as varchar(3))
)
return @ipv4

END

GO
```

MySQL Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_ConvertIPV6to4
(p_AddrIPV6 varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(17)

BEGIN

declare v_ipv4 varchar(17);

set v_ipv4 = (
select
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, Concat('0x' , substring(substring(p_AddrIPV6, (char_length(rtrim(p_AddrIPV6))-charindex(':', p_AddrIPV6)) - 3, 4), 1, 2)), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, Concat('0x' , substring(substring(p_AddrIPV6, (char_length(rtrim(p_AddrIPV6))-charindex(':', p_AddrIPV6)) - 3, 4), 3, 2)), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, Concat('0x' , substring(substring(p_AddrIPV6, (char_length(rtrim(p_AddrIPV6))-charindex(':', p_AddrIPV6)) + 2, 4), 1, 2)), 1)) as varchar(3)) + '.' +
cast(convert(int, convert(varbinary, Concat('0x' , substring(substring(p_AddrIPV6, (char_length(rtrim(p_AddrIPV6))-charindex(':', p_AddrIPV6)) + 2, 4), 3, 2)), 1)) as varchar(3))
)
return v_ipv4;

END
```

Please anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: You should look at the documentation for mysql. CAST and CONVERT are not exactly the same as they are in sql server. The parameter order is not the same.

Comment: Assume the ; character at the end of the   v_ipv4 declare you noticed already?